# Deselect by Attribute

Tags: selection-tools

I have a topologically complex mesh for which I have stored various useful edge and face selections using boolean attributes on the face and edge domains (in Properties -> Object Data -> Attributes).

In the Select menu, there is only the option to select By Attribute. What I also need is to deselect By Attribute. How can I do this? Perhaps with Python?

Comment: I'm not an expert in Python, but maybe it would be easier to simply select by attribute, then invert the selection with `Ctrl`+`I`? Of course this might become tricky (or rather impossible) if you only have some parts selected and want to subtract by attributes from that. Vertex Groups are probably better for that.

Comment: But Ctrl+I won't allow to cumulate selections

Comment: Yes, I already have an existing selection that I want to subtract from, so inverting the selection doesn't work. Vertex Groups also do not work in many situations, for example where you have some edges sharing vertices and want some edges selected but not others. For example in a quad with two opposite edges selected, the same selection as a Vertex Group will select all four edges. Likewise, with all four edges selected, trying to deselect any two edges represented as a Vertex Group will deselect all four edges instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will add two operators in edit mode, at the end of the 'Select' menu.

The first is 'Select by attribute' which should be similar to the 'By attribute' selection but allows to use inverted (false) attribute values.

The second is 'Deselect by attribute' which is what you asked for. Same principle, an option allows to use true or false values to deselect.

[image]

The code is the following. Nothing particular to say, except that attribute values and domain should be obtained in object mode (as if not this is not accessible).

You can run the script from the text editor or install it as an addon.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Deselect by attribute",
    "author": "lemon",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (3, 5, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Select > Select or Deselect by attribute",
    "description": "Select or deselect components using boolean attribute values",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Mesh",
}

import bpy, bmesh

def select_or_deselect_by_attribute(object, select, when_true):

    data = object.data
    
    # get the active attribute
    att = data.attributes.active

    # it must exist and be of boolean type
    if att is None or att.data_type != 'BOOLEAN':
        return

    # get its name    
    att_name = att.name

    # switch to objet mode in order to get attribute values
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

    # get it again by name (selected attributes are not the same in object mode)
    att = data.attributes[att_name]
    # get the values and domain
    values = [d.value for d in att.data]
    domain = att.domain
    
    # back to edit mode
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(data)

    components = None
    
    # Handle only if either vertices or edges or faces
    if domain == 'POINT':
        components = bm.verts
    elif domain == 'EDGE':
        components = bm.edges
    elif domain == 'FACE':
        components = bm.faces

    if components:
        for component, value in zip(components, values):
            # look if we want to deselect when true or false
            value = value if when_true else not value
            # select or deselect when needed
            if value:
                component.select_set(select)

    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(data)


def main(context, select, when_true):
    select_or_deselect_by_attribute(context.object, select, when_true)

class SelectByAttributeOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.select_by_attribute2"
    bl_label = "Select by attribute"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    when_true: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name = "Select when true", default=True)

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        active_obj = context.active_object
        if active_obj is None or active_obj.mode != 'EDIT':
            return False
        attribute = active_obj.data.attributes.active
        if attribute is None or attribute.data_type != 'BOOLEAN':
            return False
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context, True, self.when_true)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class DeselectByAttributeOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.deselect_by_attribute"
    bl_label = "Deselect by attribute"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    when_true: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name = "Deselect when true", default=True)

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        active_obj = context.active_object
        if active_obj is None or active_obj.mode != 'EDIT':
            return False
        attribute = active_obj.data.attributes.active
        if attribute is None or attribute.data_type != 'BOOLEAN':
            return False
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context, False, self.when_true)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(SelectByAttributeOperator.bl_idname, text=SelectByAttributeOperator.bl_label)
    self.layout.operator(DeselectByAttributeOperator.bl_idname, text=DeselectByAttributeOperator.bl_label)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SelectByAttributeOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(DeselectByAttributeOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_select_edit_mesh.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SelectByAttributeOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(DeselectByAttributeOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_select_edit_mesh.remove(menu_func)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful for me both in terms of the actual functionality and giving me insight into scripting.